# SQL Server In Memory Equivalent

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, integration-testing, dapper

My team has recently decided to move from EF to Dapper. As such we are moving a lot of the logic that was done in EF into Stored Procedures as part of our SQL Server DB. This means that a lot of the Unit Tests that we have for EF are now Integration Level tests as they involve the DB. I am looking for a way to run these tests using an In-Memory DB so I don't have to stand up a DB externally as part of the tests. I looked into SQLite but without the SP support, it would not be a fair comparison. Are there any other In-Memory DBs that would be similar to SQL Server that can be used for testing?

Comment: SQL Server has [in memory tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017)-- but it really sounds like you need to set up a "production to test" replication or integration. Frankly, I don't feel it's a solid test environment unless it's as close to identical to production as possible.

Comment: Although not embedded database (I think that's what you mean by in-memory) , you could use a SQL Server Docker container to quickly spin up a database.

Comment: @JacobH I would agree that the closer we can get to production the better. I was hoping to avoid having to do the overhead. But it is what it is and if that's what needs to be done it can be done.

Comment: @DanGuzman I actually do that for my dev machine. The automated build system isn't that far along though. It would also mean other teams need to step in to do setup on out build agents. So I'm not sure if this would work outside of my machine.But this is one of the allternatives I am looking into.

Comment: Have you considered unit testing your procs instead of as integration tests?

Comment: Before the move, how were you testing data access code? At some point, a real DB is needed. SQLite is a frequently suggestion, and it's the totally wrong one, as it's a completely different DB engine.

Comment: @DanGuzman I had not considered just testing the SPs. I was more focused on replacing the existing tests. Do you have a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: @Alejandro Before the move we were able to mock the DbSet to provide a Moq object that contained all the data. I agree on SQLite not being the right answer.

Comment: @165plo That means you never actually tested the database, but just the code that called the DB. The ideal replacement is to put Dapper behind a repository and mock it instead, that would give the most similar test you can have. But if you want to **really** test the stored procedure and the data access, there is no way around, you MUST have a real DB server to run your tests against.

Comment: @165plo, VS database unit tests and tSQLt are a couple of methods. If you already unit test using VS, that is the natural choice.

Comment: @Alejandro While you are correct the original tests didn't actually hit the DB. EF generated all the SQL that was used in making the call. The tests verified that the returned results matched what was expected. My overall goal is to get that same level of coverage.

Comment: @DanGuzman I will look into each of the options you listed. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @165plo It's true that EF generates all the SQL, but without actually *running* that SQL on the real server, there is no way to prove it was correct. At most, you can assert that the parameters sent to the DbContext were correct and then you return a hardcoded result (that has no relation to the real result). I can't see how that test add any value, unless I'm missing something, but right now, I would just replace it with a direct call to the real DB and the real stored procedure. But yes, you need to setup a local server for that.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use the local version of SQL Server, named LocalDB, that doesn't require SQL Server to be installed as a Service...just the engine is needed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

The engine will be start as soon as you'll connect to a database, with a connection string that references the LocalDB engine, and also specifies the .mdf file you want to attach:

`Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=true ;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf`

Comment: So this solution isn't in memory. But it may be the closest to matching SQL Server.